# Need my script to answer yes to a government banner

Tags: bash

So I am super new to bash scripting so please excuse my ignorance.  I have a need to ssh to multiple systems as a certain user.  I am able to complete that task, however each system has a government banner that one needs to reply to with a "yes" to accept.

I have tried using the yes option within the bash script to no avail. This seems like it should be very easy, but for a newb like me it seems to be harder.

I tried this:

```
    export TRIM_HEADER="/-- WARNING\|You are accessing a U.S./,/Agreement for details./d"
    export SSHPASS='prompt below'
    export DEBUG=${DEBUG:-}
    export SSH="$DEBUG sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=???? -t -t"

    ssh() {
           $SSH $* 2>&1 | sed -e "$TRIM_HEADER"
   }
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there an easier way?  I also looked at expect, but can't seem to get that to work either.

It is a simple yes response.

Comment: So.. `echo yes | ssh ...`?

Comment: So I put that in the script after where it has me connect?  Sorry to be such a newb

Comment: Check this thread --> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33271/how-to-avoid-ssh-asking-permission

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't what I need.  I am getting past that portion.